# When I hit sign transaction in deploying contract, the send button is greyed out

Tags: contract-development

[image: ct]

I have 0.5 ROP but it is saying send 0. My wallet address is 0xef534b8ea9B3897a014Bf47E84c642Ad7952A120

Answer (score 0):

You dont have any ropsten ETH. You need enough Ropsten ETH in your accout to cover the gas costs of the transaction. You can get some from here :https://faucet.ropsten.be/

Comment: I have 0.5 Ropsten ETH, but do I need a full, 1 Ropsten ETH to send the transaction?

Comment: Then why does it say 0 ROP at the top?

Comment: This is strange just checked etherscan and it says you should have 1 ETH which is more than enough for the transaction

Comment: https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0xef534b8ea9B3897a014Bf47E84c642Ad7952A120

Comment: Try logging out and back in.. or use metamask

Comment: I’ve logged out and in a few times and I’m having the same issue. How do I deploy a contract on MetaMask? All I’m seeing is Deposit and Send as options